# Efficient Object Search/Filtering 

Tags: java, list, search, object, filtering

In a filtering class, I've decided; for functionality purposes to get all the data from the table first, and then filter this results using the class itself. I have a list of objects that represent all the data from the table; and I would like to know what is the quickest, or more efficient, way of filtering this results to add them in a jTable.

What I'm looking for its to mimic the "Like" instruction from SQL, with Java programming.

Answer (score 2):

DBMS can have indices that will make filtering and sorting faster. And major DBMSes surely have mature and thoroughly developed algorithms. So it is much more efficient to do filtering and sorting in SQL.

On the other side, if you plan to narrow your search results, it looks reasonable to have first iteration (or several iterations) to be made against DB and subsequent ones - via Java collections API. But you should track somehow if your base result set (fetched via SQL) is still relevant.

Anyway, getting 100 000 records from DB over Internet just to select 50 of them doesn't sound good.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but to do a query every time a texfield changes its not efficient at all. I'm trying to do this the fastest/most efficient way possible.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It is a tradeoff. If there's 50 results after SQL run - it is efficient to do further filtering in java without SQL overhead. Maybe you should consider textbox input length.

Comment: @ctejada But this approach only works with narrowing criteria, so you have to track somehow if you should do another SQL query to get actual base result set.

Comment: That sounds good. Do you have any thoughts how should be the fastest way to do this in Java ?

Answer (score 1):

SQL is always faster in filtering than JAVA.

Collect the data you need, no more and no less.

Comment: This question is tagged Java, not PHP, though I suppose your logic still holds.

Comment: Yes, but its a bit slow when you try to do a querry every time a texfield changes... It'll take for ever to get some results.

Comment: Searching in JAVA instead won't make it faster, as you'd have to store the entire dataset *somewhere* in your code and run searches on that dataset everytime a textfield changes. What's the real issue here? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to do a filter of my database table that shows it in a jTable. I'm looking for the fastest way to do this; initially I thought doing this in java would be faster than performing a query over the internet every single time; but apparently I was wrong

Answer (score 1):

To mimic `LIKE` you are going to have to loop through all your objects and then on the field(s) you are about, you'll have to use something like [String.match](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) to see if the field(s) match the filtering criteria.

As Robin said, it will be more efficient to do this in SQL than to pull everything out of the database into Java and do the filtering in Java.